# Does a creature lose invisibility after being hit?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, invisibility

Duergar Scouts can turn invisible as a standard action until the end of their next turn or until *they* hit or miss with an attack.  One of the PCs guessed where the monster might be and attacked the area with a blast, hitting the creature.  At this point, there was some discussion on whether or not the monster would remain invisible.

I couldn't find anything in the **Rules Compendium** or **DMG** under "Invisibility" to cover this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**

[Invisible](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=151) states:

> If a creature is invisible, it has several advantages against creatures that can’t see it: It has total concealment against them, it doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks from them, and they grant combat advantage to it.

Therefore the invisible state itself is not "toggled" by its nature. (Unlike, for example, prone, which offers standing up as an explicit option.)

Therefore, the only rules governing when invisible is active for a given monster are within the monster's stat block.

[Duergar Scouts](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=880), the little ****s have:

> Underdark Sneak  At-Will
>
> Effect: The scout becomes invisible until the end of its next turn or until it hits or misses with an attack.

On a positive note, they only become hidden if they then take a move action (which is likely, but it means dazed is quite handy.) Unfortunately, the only way to make a duergar scout visible against its will is to kill it or use one of your powers that removes invisibility.

Comment: Does this mean an invisible creature must still make a Stealth check to become 'hidden'?

Comment: Ayep. (Unless they're an assassin with a specific feat or otherwise using a power that grants a stealth check explicitly) It's horribly counterintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

As I read though the **Rules Compendium, pg 221**, It talks about invisibility. As I read more and more the answer to your question is simple.

**NO**
It does not lose it's invisibility but the players to know where he is.

> If an invisible creature is hidden from the attacker (rolls stealth), the attacker can neither hear nor see it, and has to guess the creature's position. If the invisible creature is not hidden from the attacker, the attacker can hear it or sense some other sign of its presence and therefore knows where it is, although it still can't see the creature. ***[Rules Compendium, pg221]***

Now for the rules of perception, which I think should apply.

> If a creature finds a hidden creature, it might point the hidden creature out to others, resulting in them knowing it's location. ***[Rules Compendium, pg 150]***

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't find anything in the Rules Compendium or DMG under "Invisibility" to cover this situation.

Since the game is exception based, the rules are ofter made in a larger way for everyone and can be changed for a specific situation.

If it wasn't specified that the duergar becomes visible again after and attack (hit or miss), it would stay invisible until the end of it's turn.

So, in this situation, no, the duergar doesn't become visible after being hit.